# Changing Maximum and Minimum Values of Axis/Axes and values of intervals on axes in R

Tags: r, graph, plot, ggplot2, axis

I am trying to change the values included in, and the maximum and minimum values, of a plot in R but everything I have tried using the "axis" function (as advised by ?axis in R) isn't working. I want the values on the x axis to be between 0 and 60, going up in intervals of 10 and the values on the y axis to be between 0.0 and 0.8 with increments of 0.1.

Here is my current code:

```
pinteractiontwo <- ggplot(new.data.longsleeptime, aes( x=Stage_Three, y=Accuracy)) 
pinteractiontwo <- pinteractiontwo + xaxis(2, at = 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, labels = 10, tick = TRUE)
pinteractiontwo <- pinteractiontwo + yaxis(1, at = 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, labels = 0.1, tick = TRUE)
pinteractiontwo <- pinteractiontwo + xlab ("Time Spent in Stage Three (Minutes)") + ylab ("Accuracy")  + theme_bw()
pinteractiontwo <- pinteractiontwo + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=20)) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=20))
pinteractiontwo <- pinteractiontwo + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=20)) + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=20))                                                                              
pinteractiontwo <- pinteractiontwo + geom_smooth(colour = "black", method = "lm", size = 1.5, aes(group = 1))
```

pinteractiontwo

This brings up this graph:

[image]

The x axis is between 20 and 60 and the y axis is between 0.5 and 0.8 (not as I tried to specify with the axis function in my code).

I need to change the axes as I am comparing them to another graph so the axes need to all be on the same scale.

Please can somebody let me know where I am going wrong in my code and what I need to change?

Comment: When I've tried running the code again, it's come up with an error message saying "xaxis" and "yaxis" aren't functions so I have no amended to just "axis" for both but this still makes no changes to the plot.

Comment: Take a look at `?xlim` and `?ylim`. Docs also [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/xylim.html).

Comment: Thank you @jbaums I'll take a look later.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [scale_x_discrete & scale_y_discrete](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_discrete.html) methods.

```
xlimits <- seq(0, 60, 10)
pinteractiontwo <- pinteractiontwo + scale_x_discrete(limits=xlimits)
```

Or, as jbaums stated, there are [xlim & ylim](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/xylim.html) methods as well.

Comment: You could elaborate on this, and make sure you spell the function name correctly.

Comment: @jbaums thanks for pointing out my mistakes. Updated the answer

Comment: Thank you both. I'll try this later and let you know how it goes! And thanks @MishaSlyusarev for spotting my mistake, handed noticed that. Corrected now!